# Establish a communication link between content script and background page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, background-process

Developing a chrome extension using javascript is one of my university projects.

I don't know how to establish a communication link between content script and background page using messaging. I need some help in this establishing the connection

**background.html**

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) { 
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {method: "getHTML"}, function(response) { 
        console.log(response.data); 
    }); 
});
```

**content_script.js**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) { 
    if (request.method == "getHTML") 
        sendResponse({data: document.getElementById('header').innerHTML}); 
    else sendResponse({}); 
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few major issues:

1. You're depending on some element on the page having the ID `header`. Such IDs are at the discretion of the site designer, so very few pages actually do have that (including Google). Maybe go for something a little more universal, like the title of the page (`document.title`).
2. What does "the extension button" mean? If it means a browser action, that's a part of your extension, so you're correct in wanted to send something from the background script. This is also an easier case, as it's probable that (aside from the issue above of no Google pages having an element of ID `header`), you're just not capturing the [browser action click event](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html#event-onClicked). If it's some injected button, however, it's the other way around.

**What you want (browser action version)**

background.html (inline):

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, { method: "getHTML"}, function(response) {
      console.log(response.data);
    });
  });
});
```

content_script.js

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.method === "getHTML") {
    sendResponse({data: document.title});
  } else {
    sendResponse({});
  }
});
```

**What you might want (injected button click version)**

background.html:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.method === "getHTML") {
    console.log(request.data);
  }
});
```

content_script.js:

```
function buttonClick() {
  chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "getHTML", data: document.title});
}
```

**Code for response to comment below**

Very important recommendation: [Chrome's developer reference](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated) is probably one of the friendliest out there. If you want to know what parts of the `chrome.*` API are available, start there.

```
function getHtml(tabId) {
  chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tabId, { method: "getHTML"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
  });
}

// Note that this will only work once a tab has loaded
chrome.tabs.onSelectionChanged.addListener(function(tabId) {
  getHtml(tabId);
});

// This fires the first time a page is loaded
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo) {
  if (changeInfo.status === "complete") {
    getHtml(tabId);
  }
});
```

**Code for second response to comment below**

background.html

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.method === "getHTML") {
    console.log(request.data);
  }
});
```

content_script.js

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
  chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "getHTML", data: e.which});
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the revised code and the formatted version too. I am new to this, and haven't explored all the formatting. I am really sorry for the readbility of the code.

However, back to your code, I have tested the code and its works amazingly well, but it works only if I refresh the page on each tab.  Is it possible to make it work if I just click on a tab and the title is displayed instead of reloading the page ?

Comment: I would prefer the last version. Thanks alot with that.
So, if I want something else from the tab; for example if I want keystrokes or something like that from each tab, how would that look like(do I have to create an onkeypress Listener)? I know this is a very direct question but I really want to learn how this messaging works with different options.

Comment: I responded to your first comment with some code. You would just replace the background.html part of the browser action version. As for keystroke part, yes, you would do something like `document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) { chrome.extension.sendRequest(...) });` in the content script (injected button version). Remember to think about who's talking and who's listening: the content script should be the talker/requester if it's an interaction with the page itself, and the background script if it's some behind-the-scenes process in your extension.

Comment: i did that but now there seems to be some problem since again there is nothing being displayed ? Should I email you the code because if I post it here it might become messy again?

Comment: Nah, just see my answer above. Capturing a keypress is pretty easy.

Comment: I get an error saying : Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html. instead of actual keys. And I also tried e.keyCode but that simply gave an error.

Comment: and also why is it that it works only in stackoverflow and not in google,yahoo ?

Comment: It seems to work fine for me on a couple pages. You might want to try reloading those pages after you reload the extension. And the method of capturing keypresses is sound. [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/xaqAP/) for an example. The "resource interpreted" error message has to do with the web page itself, not your script (it means their HTTP headers are messed up so Chrome is fixing their mistake).

Comment: Thanks alot for all of this information. It's greatly appreciated. :) 
Yes,it does work. Also, last question : isn't there something for detecing the arrows, backspace,etc ?

Comment: Yes, `keydown` or `keyup` ([click here for an example using keydown](http://jsfiddle.net/JqzTq/)). Technically `keypress` is not mentioned in any specs so Chrome (and I think IE) don't care much about implementing it. I believe Firefox supports.

Comment: oo...so thats how it works. I was always confused between keydown and keyup.Inorder to obtain the tab url; do I have to write another .js file ?

Comment: You can use some of the original code above or just add `console.log(sender.tab.url)` to the background.html file (i.e. before or after the other `console.log` line). Again, I'd recommend checking [Google's documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#event-onRequest). It tells you that `chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener` receives an object, a MessageSender object, then a callback. That MessageSender contains a Tab object, which itself contains a bunch of tab properties, like its ID, title, URL, favicon, status, etc.