# localStorage doesn't work in chrome.tabs.executeScript?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I want to use `localStorage` to save and use data. I can save and use data, but when I use `localStorage` in `chrome.tabs.executeScript`, the `localStorage` is always null...why ?

my code

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({ code: 
    'document.getElementById(":2k.en").onclick = function (){
        alert(localStorage.getItem("Message"));
        document.getElementById(":2i").value = localStorage.getItem("Token");
        document.getElementById(":2k.jl").textContent = "it is OK";
    }'
});
```

Thank you !

Comment: I'm guessing you're using a content script; I had the same problem with my extension. Solution is to use `chrome.storage`, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598669/cookie-or-localstorage-with-chrome-extensions/15466494#15466494) for discussion

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you give me some example code(like how to set in bankgroud.js and how to get in content_script)? I red [link](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html), and I tried it, it doesn't work.......

Comment: There are some useful examples [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage). Does this help?

Comment: no....I want to set a value in popup.js and get value in the content_script, for set `chrome.storage.sync.set({'Message': json.data},function(){});` and for get `chrome.storage.sync.get('Message', function(){})`, I wrote this like his example, but It doesn't work...

Comment: Are you there ? Thank you

Comment: `chrome.storage` can be confusing because it is asynchronous. I would suggest that you keep trying and research about asynchronous functions, and would encourage you to post a new question if you get stuck on something specific :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think `chrome.storage` works also, but I didi it by using `chrome.extension.onRequest`

Comment: I find the answer : [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224922/establish-a-communication-link-between-content-script-and-background-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Noam Hacker, you are correct. Need to use [`Chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) API to store, retreive and track changes to user data. By using the said API you need to declare the `storage` permission in the [extension manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest) to use the storage API.

```
{
"name": "My extension",
...
"permissions": [
"storage"
],
...
```

}

Use [`get
StorageArea.get(string or array of string or object keys, function callback)`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#method-StorageArea-get) its a callback to get one or more items from storage. An empty list or object will return an empty result object. Pass in null to get the entire contents of storage.

**background.js**

This scripts sets content to chrome storage

```
//Set some content from background page
chrome.storage.local.set({"identifier":"Some awesome Content"},function (){
console.log("Storage Succesful");
});
//get all contents of chrome storage
chrome.storage.local.get(null,function (obj){
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
});
```

**popup.js**

This script retrieves and sets content from\to chrome storage

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function (){
//Fetch all contents
chrome.storage.local.get(null,function (obj){
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
});
//Set some content from browser action
chrome.storage.local.set({"anotherIdentifier":"Another awesome Content"},function (){
console.log("Storage Succesful");
});
});
```